# Excel VBA activeX component can't create object / entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found

Tags: excel, vba, regsvr32, shdocvw.internetexplorer

I have problem on running following code using Excel-VBA or cscript.exe on my PC.

```
Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
```

> “Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object”?

The above error was shown after running the code.

I have checked through Stackoverflow and found that it maybe caused by missing "shdocvw.dll" in registry.

Then, another problem comes out when I run following codes in CMD with administrative right.

```
regsvr32 shdocvw.dll
```

or

```
regsvr32 /i shdocvw.dll
```

> The module "shdocvw.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.
>
> Make sure that "shdocvw.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

I have tried regsvr32 /i "c:\windows\system32\scrrun.dll" in CMD and it works well so I am pretty sure it is not the problem of scrrun.dll.

At this point, I have no idea on this issue.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using the wrong CLSID. Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85)), it's registered as `InternetExplorer.Application`.  You need to use mshtml.tlb instead of using the .dll directly.

Comment: Thank for your reply.
I have called this library(Microsoft HTML Object Library) in Excel VBA references already.
However, the same Excel file and VBA codes works on another PC. Do you mean I should search the way to repair **mshtml.tlb** instead?